# SELECT datafields with multiple groups and sums

Tags: sql, t-sql, sorting, group-by, sql-order-by

I cant seem to group by multiple data fields and sum a particular grouped column.

I want to group Person to customer and then group customer to price and then sum price. The person with the highest combined sum(price) should be listed in ascending order.

Example:

```
table customer
-----------
customer | common_id
 green        2
 blue         2
 orange       1

table invoice
 ----------
 person | price | common_id
 bob        2330     1
 greg       360      2    
 greg       170      2

SELECT DISTINCT
    min(person) As person,min(customer) AS customer, sum(price) as price
FROM invoice a LEFT JOIN customer b ON a.common_id = b.common_id 
GROUP BY customer,price
ORDER BY person
```

The results I desire are:

```
**BOB:** 
Orange, $2230

**GREG:**
green,  $360
blue,$170

The colors are the customer, that GREG and Bob handle. Each color has a price.
```

Comment: Why `green` should match with `360` and `blue` with `170`? And not the other way around?

Comment: The colors are the customer, that GREG and Bob handle. Each color has a price.

Comment: So, you are saying that each customer has a price?

Comment: yes in reality its profit, but the column name is called price.

Comment: Still, no answer to the 1st question. Is `common_id` the `customer_id`? Or the `invoice_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues that I can see.  One is a bit picky, and one is quite fundamental.

**Presentation of data in SQL**

SQL returns tabular data sets.  It's not able to return sub-sets with headings, looking something a Pivot Table.

The means that this is not possible...

```
**BOB:** 
Orange, $2230

**GREG:**
green,  $360
blue,   $170
```

But that this *is* possible...

```
Bob,  Orange, $2230
Greg, Green,  $360
Greg, Blue,   $170
```

**Relating data**

I can visually see how you relate the data together...

```
table customer                 table invoice
--------------                 -------------
customer | common_id           person | price |common_id
 green        2                 greg     360       2
 blue         2                 greg     170       2
 orange       1                 bob     2330       1
```

But SQL doesn't have any implied ordering.  Things can only be related if an expression can state that they are related.  For example, the following is equally possible...

```
table customer                 table invoice
--------------                 -------------
customer | common_id           person | price |common_id
 green        2                 greg     170       2      \ These two have 
 blue         2                 greg     360       2      / been swapped
 orange       1                 bob     2330       1
```

This means that you need rules (and likely additional fields) that explicitly state which `customer` record matches which `invoice` record, especially when there are multiples in both with the same `common_id`.

An example of a rule could be, the lowest price always matches with the first customer alphabetically.  But then, what happens if you have ***three*** records in `customer` for `common_id = 2`, but only ***two*** records in `invoice` for `common_id = 2`?  Or do the number of records always match, and do you enforce that?

Most likely you need an extra piece (or pieces) of information to *know* which records relate to each other.

Answer (score 0):

you should group by using all your selected fields except sum then maybe the function group_concat (mysql) can help you in concatenating resulting rows of the group clause

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you could possibly do this. Greg has 2 colors, AND 2 prices, how do you determine which goes with which?

Greg Blue 170 or Greg Blue 360 ???? or attaching the Green to either price?

I think the colors need to have unique identofiers, seperate from the person unique identofiers.

Just a thought.